# Umbounded solution of Poisson's equation in case $n=2$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $f\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a function with compact support. We consider for $n=2$ the solution of Poisson equation $$u(x)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\log|x-y|f(y)\;dy,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$

Can I prove that $u(x)$ may not be bounded? I thought of proceeding in the classical way by constructing a ball around the singularity, $x$ in this case. But then I don't know how to go on. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

WLOG assume $f$ takes only positive values. (just take an absolute value otherwise.)

Let $\Omega=\operatorname{supp}f$. Then
$$u(x)=\frac{-1}{2\pi}\int_{\Omega}\log|x-x'|f(x')\mathrm d^2 x'$$
Consider $x\notin \Omega$ such that $\operatorname{dist}(x,\Omega)>1$. (This prevents the log from returning negative values). Now, because everything in the integrand is positive,
$$|u(x)|=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Omega}\log|x-x'|f(x')~\mathrm d^2x'$$

Now because $\Omega$ is compact (and due to our assumption $\operatorname{dist}(x,\Omega)>1)$, the values
$$m(x)=\min_{x'\in\Omega}\log|x-x'|~~~~,~~~~M(x)=\max_{x'\in\Omega}\log|x-x'|$$
Both exist and are finite. Hence
$$|u(x)|\geq \frac{1}{2\pi}m(x)\int_{\Omega}f(x')\mathrm d^2x' \\ |u(x)|\geq C~m(x)$$
With $C=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Omega}f(x')\mathrm d^2 x'$.

But, clearly, $m(x)$ is unbounded w.r.t $x$.

Done. The main idea of this argument is essentially that
$u(x)=C\log|x|+\mathrm O(1) ~~ \text{as}~|x|\to\infty$.

Comment: The existence of $m,M$ by the way follows from the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One last thing, what happens if $x\in\Omega$? What means that $m(x)$ is unbounded?

Comment: @NatMath We don't care about $x\in\Omega$. All we needed to do is show $u$ is unbounded, which we have. $m(x)$ being unbounded means we can make it as large as we want by choosing some $x$.